# Setting a background image in a simple java game

Tags: java, image, background

I'm making my first simple game, that looks like Space Invaders.

I have used paint for drawing my hero on my JPanel. Now I guess if it's possible, in a simple way, to add a background image on my JPanel.

```
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("back.gif"));
Image image = img.getImage();
setDoubleBuffered(true);    
hero = new Hero("hbarrel.gif",350,500); 

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.drawImage(hero.getImage(), hero.getX(), hero.getY(), this);
    g2d.drawImage(image,0,0,this);
    // Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    g.dispose();
}
```

So, this is it: I tried to use my background img as hero img, and it works! but when I use the code above it only paints my hero img.... so it isn't a resource position issue.

Comment: You should override paintComponent() in swing rather than paint(). But the current problem is not related with that, I guess. Can you check that "image.jpg" path is correct and image is correctly loaded.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Override `paintComponent(Graphics)` method and use `Graphics.drawImage()` to do that in your own custom component.

Comment: it shows only my "hero" image, not the background image. I have

Comment: sorry this is my real comment:

Answer (score 0):

Well, try to paint the background image first and then the hero so that you have hero above background image